# Indesign 5.5 Create elbow connector?

Tags: adobe-indesign

I am trying to create an elbow connector between two boxes on a flow chart. for some reason I am not having success. 
Whenever I use the Pen tool to create the points it automatically creates a line joining the first and last points of the connector. Imagine a line connecting the two arrow heads on the example shown here.

I would appreciate an ELI5 explanation of how to do this.

[image: Elbow connector from PowerPoint]

Comment: Not sure I understand. You should *easily* be able to create that path with arrows in Indesign using the Pen Tool. I don't get any "auto-close" of paths here.

Comment: Yeah. After doing it a dozen times and getting a diagonal auto-close it seems to have worked on the 13th try. not sure what I did differently. Should I have been entering the points in a specific order? e.g. first, last, elbow 1, elbow 2, or First, E1, E2, last

Comment: I can't get it to auto-close, maybe you had a [fill applied](http://i.imgur.com/6OtcCq5.png) to your object? The easiest sequence should be the same sequence you would take to draw the same path with a physical pen/pencil (like you said, F, E1, E2, L). Alternately, you could do F, L (a diagonal), and then add the elbows, but then you'd have to manually move the elbows to the positions you wanted them in (they'd default inline with the diagonal).

Comment: you know, there could have been a fill applied to it before i even started making the points. thanks Scott and apex for your input.

Answer (score 0):

There are some shape libraries here for InDesign you can try 
http://www.jjg.net/ia/visvocab/#conclude

The connectors cater for horizontal and vertical joins. The arrow tips are built on the connector.

Thanks